# How do I hide an active street view panorama in google maps api v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

What is the command to exit street view, when using api v3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the StreetViewPanorama that is bound to the map, then set its visibility to false:

```
var panorama = map.getStreetView();
panorama.setVisible(false);
```

Or to do it in one line:

```
map.getStreetView().setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Here is an excerpt from a jQuery plugin that I wrote:


        this.setTypeRoadMap = function () {
            this.map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
        }
        this.setTypeSatellite = function () {
            this.map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
        }
        this.setTypeHybrid = function () {
            this.map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);
        }
        this.setTypeTerrain = function () {
            this.map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        }
```

You call the 'setMapTypeId' function with one of the above enum values. BTW here is the full jQuery plugin: http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/a-google-maps-version-3-jquery-plugin/

Hope this helps.

Bob